# Is it possible to have Crop marks for camera alignment and visualizing purposes?

Tags: pagelayout

I am looking for a simple way to put crop margins in Mathematica's PDF output like the *Crop* package in Latex. Could be this done with Mathematica's Frontend or do I have to use an external program?

Comment: My guess is that you have to use external software.  But I've been wrong many times in the past when I said that something was not possible.

Comment: [This answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9460/17) might be related, though maybe not exactly what you need.

Comment: @Silvia I know this posting! I appreciate your valuable contributations a lot! I send a question how to have different page margins for odd and even pages like in latex. Do you have some ideas?

Comment: @kornaros Sorry for replying late. I'm afraid that answer is all I know about MMA's PDF ability. But on the other hand, maybe you can try layout everything manually, say, in a `Grid`, with the real page-margins set to 0.