# Deleting the header footer in the PDF output of a Mathematica code

Tags: export, pdf-format

I just saved my Mathematica notebook as a PDF file and realized that every page (except the first one) consists of a header footer (I don't know whether this is the correct name or not) indicating the page number and the file name. How can I delete this header from my document? This is important since I will insert this PDF file into my thesis, so even if the answer is nothing to do with Mathematica I will be keen on listening any comments and guidance.

Comment: See this answer: [Some tutorials on formatting notebook for exporting to PDF](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/some-tutorials-on-formatting-notebook-for-exporting-to-pdf)

Comment: Thanks, that really solved the problem.

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help!