# Save as PDF without cell numbers

Tags: export, notebooks, pdf-format, cells

I want to save a notebook file as PDF, but without cell numbers.

For instance, take this document,

[image: Mathematica document]

then select “save as PDF” and the result is,

[image: PDF output]

How can I remove the cell numbers `In[14]`, `In[16]`, and `Out[16]`?

Comment: I guess this may be useful...
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/some-tutorials-on-formatting-notebook-for-exporting-to-pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want, I think, is the cell option `ShowCellLabel -> False`.  You can edit the stylesheet to add the option to the styles `"Input"` and `"Output"` in the `"Printout"` environment.  Or you can add them to a notebook, assuming it has the default style definitions, as follows:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
    Cell[StyleData["Input", "Printout"], ShowCellLabel -> False], 
    Cell[StyleData["Output", "Printout"], ShowCellLabel -> False]}]]
```

As Alexey Popkov points out, it can be done more simply with

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowCellLabel -> False]
```

or for the current session (affecting all notebook temporarily) with

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, ShowCellLabel -> False]
```

Comment: Actually the same can be achieved much simpler by setting the same option at the Notebook level: `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowCellLabel -> False]`. Note also that this option can also be set globally, for example `SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, ShowCellLabel -> False]` works (checked by saving as PDF with version 10.4.1).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Well, what do you know.  I'm sure I tried that and was surprised it didn't work.  In fact the code is still in my scratch notebook.  Works now, though.

Answer (score 4):

Evaluate this and then save as another nb, open the new nb file, and then save as PDF

```
SetOptions[InputNotebook[], CellLabelAutoDelete -> True];
```