# How to download a categorized pdf version of the latest version of Mathematica's documentation?

Tags: documentation, pdf-format

In my opinion, it is difficult to find and study subjects in the current documentation of Mathematica (both offline and website) and I prefer to study a PDF version.

But unlike MATLAB and Python, Wolfram does not provide the PDF version of its documentation. However, I know that the documentation pages can be saved as PDF file.

How can I create or download a categorized pdf of the whole of the latest version of Mathematica's documentation ?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do that? There is no particular order to the documentation so it would be hard to say which article should go first, and you'd also be missing out on, in my opinion, the most powerful feature of Mathematica's documentation: the ability to change the examples in the documentation to play around with them on the fly. It would also be thousands of pages long. If you really want to, I would guess you'd either need to crawl reference.wolfram.com or the Documentation folder in your installation and export each one as a PDF. Perhaps someone else will have a better idea.

Comment: The PDF version of the documentation [was available up to version 5.2](https://reference.wolfram.com/history/) and it is about 27 MB and 1486 pages! Considering the fact that the Wolfram language has grown much larger since then, I guess they don't produce a PDF version simply because it would be huge. [For comparison](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/253209/37848), the number of keywords in the current version (12.3.1) is more than 3.5 times. I can't imagine why would anybody want such a pdf

Comment: Unlike Mathematica, MATLAB publishes a massive collection of PDF version for each version the software. Number of pages of some of these files is much larger than 10k pages (some above 100k). Since the pages of Mathematica's documentation can be saved as PDF, users should also be able to create the PDF documentation but how is my question. @polfosol

Comment: Of course, any official release of PDF version of Wolfram's documentation or any instruction from the officials is most appreciated.

Comment: * I was wondering if anyone interested could upvote this question.

Comment: If you are on Windows, there is a built-in virtual printer ["Microsoft Print to PDF"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Spi5.png). It's a component of Windows, I believe it has official APIs one can access, say, through .NET.

Comment: MS print to PDF on the webpages does not detect the example parts even with "open all". I could not understand how the the documentation files are categorized in the installation location.
I was wondering if you could explain in more detail. @Silvia

Comment: @Alex97 Documentation notebooks are not categorized by folders and names, but can be analyzed by their `TaggingRules`.

Comment: @Alex97 I guess you can follow the categories from [the home page of documentation center](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/). BTW I meant to suggest printing from local documentation notebooks instead of webpages. Please see my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9460/17) for reference.